# Databinding listbox to a list<string[]>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I am having hard luck in trying to bind my property which is of type List to a ListBox through XAML. Note though that the list contains string arrays (string[]).

So the XAML part of code looks like this:

```
<ListBox Height="373" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,65,0,0" Name="reservoirList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="546" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Wells}">
</ListBox>
```

and on the viewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<string[]> Wells {
            get { return new ObservableCollection<string[]>(getWellsWithCoords()); }            
        }
```

where getWellsWithCoords() creates a list of string[].

When I ran the application what I see is - which makes sense:

```
string[] array
string[] array 
....
```

Is it possible to change the XAML code in such a way so that automatically on each row
I see the n values of the each element of the Wells list, i.e something like:

```
well1 value11 value12
well2 value21 value22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a template to your listbox:

```
<ListBox Height="373" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,65,0,0" Name="reservoirList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="546" ItemsSource="{Binding Wells}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!--Here you bind the array-->
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <!--Here you bind the value of each string-->
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own class for holding this data:

```
public class WellInfo
{
    private string[] _infos;
    public WellInfo(string[] infos)
    {
        this._infos = infos;
    }
    public string DisplayValue
    {
        get { return this._infos.Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next); }
    }
}
```

The use that in your collection:

```
public IEnumerable<WellInfo> Wells
{
    get { return getWellsWithCoords().Select(x => new WellInfo(x)); }            
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<ListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Wells}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="DisplayValue" />
```